# How can I get in jquery the second id, third, and fourth , etc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've tried to get the second id of the div to delete a product, but whenever I list the "DVD product" in PHP, I just can get the first one. The second forward isn't work. It only works when I delete the first. How can I fix that?

```
<?php foreach($dvdLists as $key => $dvdList) { ?>
   <div class="product-dvd" id="<?= $dvdList->id_dvd ?>">
      <input class="delete-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkDvd">
      <p> <?= $dvdList->sku ?>  </p>
      <p> <?= $dvdList->name ?> DVD </p>
      <p> <?= $dvdList->price?> $ </p>
      <p> Size: <?= $dvdList->size ?> MB </p>
  </div> 
<?php } ?>



$('#delete-product-btn').click(function(){
    if($("div.product-dvd > input.delete-checkbox").is(':checked')) { 
        var getId = $('[class="product-dvd"]').attr('id');
       alert('your id='+getId);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your rendered HTML, not the PHP. It's easier for us to help you if we have a sample of the code you're working with.

Comment: Try: `var checked = $(".product-dvd > .delete-checkbox:checked")`.  then you can do `if (checked.length)` and loop through or `map` `checked` to get your IDs, depending on your requirement.

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/is/ *return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments* - so if your second tickbox is ticked, then the `if` passes - then your `$("[..]").attr` always gets from the first, regardless of whether its checkbox is ticked or not.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to go through all the divs and get the selected IDs. You can delete them one by one, or you can delete them collectively by collecting the IDs and sending them to the backend at once.

```
$('.product-dvd').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.delete-checkbox').is(':checked')){
        let getId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert('delete: ' + getId);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.attr()` only evaluates the first element.

Also note that `.is()` will return true if at least one element matches the condition, so your current code ends up with all checkboxes if just one box is checked.

I think you have two options here, either select all `div.product-dvd` and then filter by checked checkbox or select all checked checkboxes and the go up to the `div.product-dvd`.

To select all `div.product-dvd` and then filter by checked checkbox, use `.has()`:

```
const ids = $('div.product-dvd')
  .has('.delete-checkbox:checked')
  .map(function(index, element){
    return $(element).attr('id')
  }).toArray()
```

```js
$('#delete-product-btn').click(function() {
  const ids = $('div.product-dvd')
    .has('.delete-checkbox:checked')
    .map(function(index, element){
      return $(element).attr('id')
    }).toArray()
  console.clear()
  console.log('Deleting', JSON.stringify(ids))
});
```

```html
<div class="product-dvd" id="product-1">
  <label>
    <input class="delete-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkDvd">
    Product 1
  </label>
</div>

<div class="product-dvd" id="product-2">
  <label>
    <input class="delete-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkDvd">
    Product 2
  </label>
</div>

<div class="product-dvd" id="product-3">
  <label>
    <input class="delete-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkDvd">
    Product 3
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="delete-product-btn">delete</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

To select all checked checkboxes and the go up to the `div.product-dvd`, use `.closest()`:

```
const ids = $('div.product-dvd > input.delete-checkbox:checked')
  .closest('.product-dvd')
  .map(function(index, element){
    return $(element).attr('id')
  }).toArray()
```

```js
$('#delete-product-btn').click(function() {
  const ids = $('div.product-dvd input.delete-checkbox:checked')
    .closest('.product-dvd')
    .map(function(index, element){
      return $(element).attr('id')
    }).toArray()
  console.clear()
  console.log('Deleting', JSON.stringify(ids))
});
```

```html
<div class="product-dvd" id="product-1">
  <label>
    <input class="delete-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkDvd">
    Product 1
  </label>
</div>

<div class="product-dvd" id="product-2">
  <label>
    <input class="delete-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkDvd">
    Product 2
  </label>
</div>

<div class="product-dvd" id="product-3">
  <label>
    <input class="delete-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkDvd">
    Product 3
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="delete-product-btn">delete</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eq function and pass the index 1 in this case to get second element.

```
$('#delete-product-btn').click(function(){
    var secondDiv = $("div.product-dvd").eq(1);
    if(secondDiv.find("input.delete-checkbox").is(':checked')) { 
        var getId = secondDiv.attr('id');
       alert('your id='+getId);
    }
});
```